# Spring boot authentication - admin console 403 response to client

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I'm using jdk 1.8 and Spring boot 2.1.2.

I would like to enable authentication in administration console of Spring Boot and in its clients.

I setted in *Administration* **application.properties**:

```
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=secret

spring.boot.admin.discovery.enabled=true

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET,POST
```

In *Administration* project I added this class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecuritySecureConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecuritySecureConfig.class);

    private final String adminContextPath;

    public SecuritySecureConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
        this.adminContextPath = adminServerProperties.getContextPath();
    }

    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
    successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(adminContextPath + "/");

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage(adminContextPath + "/login").successHandler(successHandler).and()
            .logout().logoutUrl(adminContextPath + "/logout").and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .ignoringAntMatchers(
                    adminContextPath + "/instances",
                    adminContextPath + "/actuator/**"
            );

    }

}
```

In *administration* **pom.xml** I added:

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>      
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I was forced to add the annotation *@EnableWebFluxSecurity* on the main class because without it, it gives an Exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/reactive/ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=springSecurityFilterChain; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/reactive/ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]]
>   for bean 'springSecurityFilterChain': There is already [Root bean:
>   class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=springSecurityFilterChain; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]]
>   bound.

In *client* **application.properties**:

```
spring.security.user.name=joe
spring.security.user.password=my-secret-password

spring.boot.admin.client.username=admin
spring.boot.admin.client.password=secret

spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.name=admin
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.password=secret


spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=true

spring.boot.admin.client.auto-registration=true
spring.boot.admin.client.auto-deregistration=true
```

And in client **pom.xml**:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Now if I access both of them using the browser, they prompt me with the login form. I type the login and password and all works as a charm, but the actuator of the client cannot access to the admin, it returns always 403 FORBIDDEN.

> 2019-02-12 15:21:52.004 - [registrationTask1] DEBUG
>   o.s.core.log.CompositeLog.debug 142 - Response 403 FORBIDDEN

I really cannot understand why the communication between the administration console and the client does not work. 
Does anyone know where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem
so, use

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
```

and not

```
@EnableWebSecurity
```

like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig   {

    private final AdminServerProperties adminServer;

    public AppSecurityConfig (AdminServerProperties adminServer) {
        this.adminServer = adminServer;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/instances")))
            .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/actuator/**")))
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl(this.adminServer.getContextPath() + "/logout")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    } }
```

in you application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      password: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      name: ${ADMIN_USER}
  application:
    name: Admin Server 
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        username: ${ADMIN_USER}
        password: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
        url: ${ADMIN_SERVER_URL}
        enabled: true
      ui:
        cache:
          no-cache: true
        title: App Monitoring
        instance:
          name: ${spring.application.name}
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
      cors:
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: GET,POST
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

It can monitor it self if you want

---

in the client side app

```
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        url: ${ADMIN_SERVER_URL}
        username: ${ADMIN_USER}
        password: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
        instance:
          name: ${spring.application.name}
        auto-registration: true
  application:
    name: Client App
```